# Is this basic understanding of a representation correct?

Tags: representation-theory

I am a complete newby to Representation Theory, so please forgive my naivety. Having done some searching online I think I'm right in saying a representation is a homomorphism which maps a group to $GL_n(K)$. Using this representation, whatever it is, we can manipulate the original objects with the well understood tools of linear algebra, and then transform back to the original objects via the inverse, which exists since we have a homomorphism.

I have two questions **(1)** is my very rough understanding correct, and **(2)** can a representation also take a **ring** to $GL_n(K)$ ? I think (2) is true because every ring is a group.

Comment: It can't take a ring to $GL_n(K)$, because $0$ is in a ring, and $0$ is not in $GL_n(K)$. Representation theory can be applied to rings by creating a ring homomorphism from the ring $R$ to $M_n(K)$, the ring of $n\times n$ matrices over $K$. Indeed, there is a ring, $R=K[G]$ such any representation of the group $G$ is equivalent to a ring representation of $K[G]$. $K[G]$ is called the "group ring."

Comment: (You could, in theory, consider a ring as an abelian group, and talk about the representations of that group, but this is essentially ignoring the "interesting" parts of the ring - the multiplicative structure of the ring.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) is correct.

(2) not quite.  It is true that every ring is an abelian additive group, but a commutative operation is not a very good tool for representing groups (most of which are non-abelian).  If you take a nonabelian group $G$ and try to represent it in a familiar additive one, most of $G$ will end up in the kernel of the homomorphism.

The groups $\text{GL}_{n}(K)$ are noncommutative, hence able, on the one hand, to capture the noncommutativity of the group we are trying to represent, and on the other hand, to convert, as you said, the elements of the group to linear transformations; i.e., objects which allow calculation, including by computer.

An excellent source (literally, the first 60 pages will give you a solid background) is Serre's book *Linear representations of finite groups*.

Another one, at least to browse the chapters of interest to you, is Pontryagin's monograph *Topological groups*.